# Testing a public method that calls subscribe on private property angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm currently in the process of learning angular 2 and working on some unit tests for an app. I have service that's similar to the following:

```
    @Injectable()
  export class ModalService{      
    private onClose  = new Subject<boolean>();
    public subscribeOnModalClose(closeHandler:any):void {
      this.onClose.subscribe(closeHandler);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly how I should go about testing `subscribeOnModalClose()`. I'm thinking just that I should make sure `.subscribe()` gets called when the actual method gets called. But i'm honestly not sure how to check that, considering the onClose$ is a private property.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You only posted (I guess) a small part of the service. If I understand correctly, the contract of the method is to make sure the closeHandler is closed when you close the modal. So, pass a spy to subscribeOnClose(), then close the modal, then verify that the spy has been called.

Comment: awesome, so simple and to the point. thank you! It seemed like such a weird method to test :).